# How do I make my script launch the screen as non-root

Tags: ubuntu, root, gnu-screen

I'm running Minecraft, starting it automatically from from `/etc/rc.local`. I have that run `/home/kent-server/mc/spigot.sh` and inside that is `screen -dms minecraft Java -jar -Xmx5120M -Xms5120M spigot.jar`.

The code itself does it's job but it launches the screen under `S-root` not `S-kent-server`. This is problematic because when I login to my normal user it will not show any screens running.  But when I switch to root using the `su` command it shows it just fine.

Comment: `su - <user> -c <cmd>` will help.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by *Drav Sloan* you can use `su` like:

`su -l kent-server -c 'cd /home/kent-server/mc/ && screen -d -m -S Minecraft Java -jar -Xmx5120M -Xms5120M spigot.jar'`

It is also possble to ahcieve a similar result using `sudo` such as:

`sudo -u kent-server /home/kent-server/mc/spigot.sh`

Comment: Now no sockets are showing up.... The code I have in rc.local is sh sudo -u kent-server /home/kent-server/mc/spigot.sh

Comment: Nevermind that first solution helped turns out I forgot I had a #!/bin/bash command inside the folder that directed the rc.local to spigot and when I added that code it worked thank you!